# JS How to get the deepest (last) children of a node

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, parent, children

I want to get all children of a node and use `.click()` method on them in JS.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: [How do I ask and self-answer a correct, high quality Q&A pair without attracting downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/how-do-i-ask-and-self-answer-a-correct-high-quality-qa-pair-without-attracting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found any better than write this script, hope it help someone:

```
const getLastChildren = (parent: Element): Element[] => {
  return Array.from(parent.children).reduce<Element[]>((acc, node) => {
    const children = Array.from(node.children);
    if (children.length === 0) {
      acc.push(node);
      return acc;
    }
    return [...acc, ...getLastChildren(node)];
  }, []);
};
```

(without typescript):

```
const getLastChildren = (parent) => {
  return Array.from(parent.children).reduce((acc, node) => {
    const children = Array.from(node.children);
    if (children.length === 0) {
      acc.push(node);
      return acc;
    }
    return [...acc, ...getLastChildren(node)];
  }, []);
};
```